# avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied - can't get out of that

Tags: uploading, avrdude

I have an Arduino Pro Micro ATmega32U4 and I'm facing this error message on uploading:

```
         Copyright (c) Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "//etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/lucas/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
avrdude: opening programmer "avr109" on port "/dev/ttyACM0" failed

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/sections/360003198300 for suggestions.
```

I can upload code if I open Arduino IDE through terminal with `sudo`, but I don't know if there is any problem with this.

the stats for ttyACM0 shows up like this

```
~ >>> stat /dev/ttyACM0                                                                                                                                                                                          
    Arquivo: /dev/ttyACM0
    Tamanho: 0          Blocos: 0          bloco de E/S: 4096   arquivo especial de caractere
Dispositivo: 0,5        Inode: 1319        Ligações: 1     Tipo de dispositivo: 166,0
     Acesso: (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  987/    uucp)
     Acesso: 2022-10-23 17:13:33.897457466 -0300
Modificação: 2022-10-23 17:13:33.897457466 -0300
  Alteração: 2022-10-23 17:13:33.897457466 -0300
    Criação: 2022-10-23 17:13:33.307457434 -0300
```

I've tried:

`sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`

`sudo usermod -a -G uucp myUser`

`sudo udevadm trigger`

And none of these worked, this error keeps showing when I use the IDE as my regular 'non root' user (Before someone ask, yes, I logged off and entered again, to make sure that the groups were updated).

So, is there any other step that I'm missing?

Comment: `every time that I try to flash anything to it I get this message` ... that is not true ... you said `I can upload code opening Arduino IDE` .... please edit your post to describe the problem exactly

Comment: It doesn't normally manifest in a permission error, but I might as well mention while you're at this to make sure you have ModemManager disabled. Otherwise it may not be as obvious when you've fixed your current problem if it's there creating a similar looking one.

Comment: Is this Linux?  Did you check the default permissions and ownership of the /dev/ttyACM0 device (when it is newly created / before you alter it)? How's about your self - did you check what groups your login belongs to? Ultimately you can edit the Linux UDEV rules, but that's a bit drastic and we should look for a simpler solution.

Comment: At the risk of annoying you, check `id -Gn` to be sure that effective group membership really has propagated. This something that hasn't been shown. `sudo udevadm trigger` isn't going to anything for you if you haven't been messing with udev rules. "Permission denied" the string version of `EACCES` coming from the `open` call in avrdude's `ser_posix.c`. If everything said is correct, the only other pain points are things like SELINUX, AppArmor, snap, or other security/sandbox/container/virtualization environment.

Comment: well I checked a few stuff, my user belongs to the same group (uucp) as the device file, I've searched a little bit more about udev rules and added the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-embedded_devices.rules` and the only line I've added is `SUBSYSTEMS="usb", ATTRS{product}== "Arduino Micro", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"` but nothing changed apparently